# Draw persistent homology barcodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, draw

I am trying to draw persistent-homology barcodes and I have no idea how to go about it. It would have to be something like that:

[image]

(Example taken from p. 56 of "Topological Persistence in Geometry and Analysis", Polterovich et al.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show us your TeX code ...

Comment: I don't even know how to start...

Comment: @juan1243 To start there is the documentation in .pdf of TikZ-pgf. or the other tag that I have added.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, that was really helpful!! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{    
    mypoint/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        inner sep=.3mm
        },  
    whitepoint/.style={
        fill=white, 
        mypoint
        },  
    blackpoint/.style={
        fill=black, 
        mypoint
        },  
    textnode/.style={
        text height=2.5ex, 
        text depth=1ex
        },  
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[-latex] (-.5,0) -- (3,0); \draw[dashed, lightgray] (0,0) -- (0,.8);
\draw[dashed, lightgray] (1,0) -- (1,.8);
\draw[dashed, lightgray] (1.732,0) -- (1.732,.9);
\draw[dashed, lightgray] (2,0) -- (2,.9);
\foreach \x in  {0,1,1.732,2}
\node[blackpoint] at (\x,0){};
\foreach \x in  {0,1,2}
\node[textnode] at (\x,-.2) {\x};
\node[textnode] at (1.732,-.2) {$\sqrt{3}$};
\node[textnode] at (2.9,-.2) {$t$};
\node[whitepoint] (h01) at (0,.2){};
\draw (0,.2) node[whitepoint] {} -- (3,.2);
\foreach \x in  {.3,.4,...,.7}
\draw (0,\x) node[whitepoint] {} -- (1,\x) node[blackpoint] {};
\draw (1,.8) node[whitepoint] {} --  node[above]{$H_1$} (1.732,.8) node[blackpoint] {};
\draw (1.732,.9) node[whitepoint] {} -- node[above]{$H_2$} (2,.9) node[blackpoint] {};
\draw (0,.1) -- ++(-.1,0) -- node[left]{$H_0$}  ++(0,.7) -- ++(.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A trivial PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=3cm,yunit=1.2cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-.25,-.5)(2.25,2.25)
    \psline[arrowinset=0]{->}(-.25,0)(2.25,0)
    \psset{linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 1pt}
    \psline(0,0)(0,1.7)
    \psline(1,0)(1,1.7)
    \psline(!3 sqrt 0)(!3 sqrt 1.9)
    \psline(2,0)(2,1.9)
    \psset{linecolor=black,linestyle=solid}
    \foreach \i/\j in {0/0,1/1,{3/\sqrt{3}},4/2}{%
        \pscircle*(!\i\space sqrt 0){2pt}
        \rput(!\i\space sqrt -.35){$\j$}}
    \rput(2.2,-.35){$t$}
    \psline{o-}(0,.5)(2.25,.5)
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{\psline{o-*}(!0 .5 0.2 \i\space mul add)(!1 .5 0.2 \i\space mul add)}
    \psline{o-*}(1,1.7)(!3 sqrt 1.7)
    \psline{o-*}(!3 sqrt 1.9)(2,1.9)
    \rput(1.35,1.9){$H_1$}
    \rput(!3 sqrt .15 add 2.1){$H_2$}
    \rput(-.17,1){$H_0$}
    \psline(0,1.6)(-.05,1.6)(-.05,.4)(0,.4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where are our comments?

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998: Deleted by our beloved moderators.

Comment: You think, what is the reason?

Answer (score 9):

For a sligthly different TikZ solution using `arrows` (and `calc` for `sqrt(3)`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    % Vertical dashed lines
    \draw[dashed, lightgray] (0,0) -- (0,.8);
    \draw[dashed, lightgray] (1,0) -- (1,.8);
    \draw[dashed, lightgray] ({sqrt(3)},0) -- ({sqrt(3)},.9);
    \draw[dashed, lightgray] (2,0) -- (2,.9);
    % Axis
    \draw [-latex,shorten >=-3pt] (-.2,0) -- (3,0) node [below] {$\phantom{\sqrt{3}}t\phantom{\sqrt{3}}$};
    \foreach \x in  {0,1,2}
        \node at (\x,0) {$\bullet$}
         node at (\x,0) [below] {$\phantom{\sqrt{3}}\x\phantom{\sqrt{3}}$};
    \node at ({sqrt(3)},0) {$\bullet$}
     node at ({sqrt(3)},0) [below] {$\sqrt{3}$};
    % Horizontal lines
    \draw [{*[fill=white]}-,shorten <=-2.4pt] (0,.2) -- (3,.2);
    \foreach \x in  {.3,.4,...,.7}
        \draw [{*[fill=white]}-*,shorten >=-2.4pt,shorten <=-2.4pt] (0,\x) -- (1,\x) ;
    \draw [{*[fill=white]}-*,shorten >=-2.4pt,shorten <=-2.4pt] (1,.8) --  node [above] {$H_1$} ({sqrt(3)},.8) ;
    \draw [{*[fill=white]}-*,shorten >=-2.4pt,shorten <=-2.4pt] ({sqrt(3)},.9) -- node [above] {$H_2$} (2,.9) ;
    \draw (0,.1) -- (-.1,.1) -- node[left]{$H_0$} (-.1,.8) -- (0,.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the somewhat less desirable (bullets are not centred nor the same size as arrow tips) output:
[image: tikz with arrows]

Also, shortenings are a bit of a guess and likely not pixel perfect.

**EDIT:** Another solution using `arrows.meta` that solves most issues of the above code but somewhat less elegant in some parts:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\begin{document}
% Arrows are shifted by half their width
\tikzset{open/.style={{Circle[fill=white]}-,shorten <=-1.196825pt-1.595769\pgflinewidth}}
\tikzset{close/.style={-{Circle},shorten >=-1.196825pt-1.595769\pgflinewidth]}}
\tikzset{openclose/.style={{Circle[fill=white]}-{Circle},shorten <=-1.196825pt-1.595769\pgflinewidth,shorten >=-1.196825pt-1.595769\pgflinewidth]}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    % Vertical dashed lines
    \draw[dashed, lightgray] (0,0) -- (0,.8);
    \draw[dashed, lightgray] (1,0) -- (1,.8);
    \draw[dashed, lightgray] ({sqrt(3)},0) -- ({sqrt(3)},.9);
    \draw[dashed, lightgray] (2,0) -- (2,.9);
    % Axis
    \draw [close] (-.2,0) -- (0,0) node [below] {$\phantom{\sqrt{3}}0\phantom{\sqrt{3}}$};
    \draw [close] (0,0) -- (1,0) node [below] {$\phantom{\sqrt{3}}1\phantom{\sqrt{3}}$};
    \draw [close] (1,0) -- ({sqrt(3)},0) node [below] {$\sqrt{3}$};
    \draw [close] ({sqrt(3)},0) -- (2,0) node [below] {$\phantom{\sqrt{3}}2\phantom{\sqrt{3}}$};
    \draw [-latex,shorten >=-3pt] (2,0) -- (3,0) node [below] {$\phantom{\sqrt{3}}t\phantom{\sqrt{3}}$};
    % Horizontal lines
    \draw [open] (0,.2) -- (3,.2);
    \foreach \x in  {.3,.4,...,.7}
    \draw [openclose] (0,\x) -- (1,\x) ;
    \draw [openclose] (1,.8) --  node [above] {$H_1$} ({sqrt(3)},.8) ;
    \draw [openclose] ({sqrt(3)},.9) -- node [above] {$H_2$} (2,.9) ;
    \draw (0,.1) -- (-.1,.1) -- node[left]{$H_0$} (-.1,.8) -- (0,.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And its (way better in my opinion) output:
[image: tikz with arrows.meta]

Comment: If you use `arrows.meta` then it is possible to fill arrows with a different colour to the one on the main path so that might solve the transparent arrow problem.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Actually `arrows.meta` was not necessary for this, but I’ve updated the code thanks to your suggestion as well as added a second version based on `arrows.meta` instead of `arrows`. ;)

Answer (score 7):

And a plain [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) version, for further comparison.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\def\strut{\vrule width 0pt height 10pt depth 0pt}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
numeric u, v;
u = 80;
v = 8;

path axis;
axis = 16 left -- 2.7u * right;

picture dot, opendot;
dot = image(fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam);
opendot = image(draw dot; unfill fullcircle scaled 3/4 dotlabeldiam);

z0 = (0, 8v);
z1 = (u, 8v);
z2 = (2u, 9v);
z3 = (1.73205u, 9v);

ahangle := 36;
drawarrow axis;
dotlabel.bot("\strut $0$", (x0, 0));
dotlabel.bot("\strut $1$", (x1, 0));
dotlabel.bot("\strut $2$", (x2, 0));
dotlabel.bot("\strut $\sqrt3$", (x3, 0));

label.rt("$t$", point 1 of axis);
forsuffixes @=0,1,2,3:
    draw (x@, 0) -- z@ dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor 3/4;
    dotlabel.bot("\strut $" if @=3: & "\sqrt" fi & decimal @ & "$", (x@, 0));
endfor

path p; p = (origin -- point 1 of axis) shifted (0, 2v);
draw p; draw opendot shifted point 0 of p;

for y=3 upto 7:
    path p; p = (x0, y*v) -- (x1, y*v);
    draw p; draw opendot shifted point 0 of p;
    draw dot shifted point 1 of p;
endfor

path p; p = (x1, 8v) -- (x3, 8v);
draw p; draw opendot shifted point 0 of p;
draw dot shifted point 1 of p; 
label.top("$H_1$", point 1/2 of p);

path p; p = (x3, 9v) -- (x2, 9v);
draw p; draw opendot shifted point 0 of p;
label.top("$H_2$", point 1/2 of p);
draw dot shifted point 1 of p;

path p; p = (x0, 7.5v) -- (x0-4, 7.5v) -- (x0-4, 1.5v) -- (x0, 1.5v);
draw p; label.lft("$H_0$", point 3/2 of p);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

**NB**: Compile with `lualatex`

If you want to give the `H_2` label more space, then just set the x part of `z3` to something a bit less than `sqrt(3)` as in the original.

Answer (score 4):

A bit with Asymptote. Compile on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
size(300,100,false);

defaultpen(linewidth(0.6bp));
dotfactor=7;

real s=0.1;
// Last drawing
draw((0,0)--(0,0.2+6s)^^(1,0)--(1,0.2+6s)^^
     (sqrt(3),0)--(sqrt(3),0.2+7s)^^(2,0)--(2,0.2+7s),linetype(new real[]{7,7})+gray);

draw(Label("$t$",Relative(.96)),(-0.2,0)--(2.8,0),Arrow);
dot("$0$",(0,0),2S,Fill());
dot("$1$",(1,0),2S,Fill());
dot("$\sqrt{3}$",(sqrt(3),0),S,Fill());
dot("$2$",(2,0),2S,Fill());
draw((0,0.2)--(2.8,0.2));
dot((0,0.2),Fill(white));

for (int i=1; i<=5 ; i=i+1)
{
  draw((0,0.2+i*s)--(1,0.2+i*s));
  dot((0,0.2+i*s),Fill(white));
  dot((1,0.2+i*s),Fill());
}

draw(Label("$H_1$",Relative(.4),LeftSide),(1,0.2+6s)--(sqrt(3),0.2+6s));
dot((1,0.2+6s),Fill(white));
dot((sqrt(3),0.2+6s),Fill());

draw(Label("$H_2$",LeftSide),(sqrt(3),0.2+7s)--(2,0.2+7s));
dot((sqrt(3),0.2+7s),Fill(white));
dot((2,0.2+7s),Fill());

draw(Label("$H_0$"),(0,0.2+5.5s)--(-s/2,0.2+5.5s)--(-s/2,0.2+-0.5s)--(0,0.2+-0.5s));
```

[image]